# Scipy label dilation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Similar to my question about [eroding a scipy label array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8580518/512652), I'm trying to dilate label regions.

The tricky part is keeping the different regions from "invading each other."

Starting with `A`, how can I get something like `B`?

```
A = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

B = array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
           [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
           [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

There are some cases that are ambiguous, and I'm not quite sure how it should behave, but I think what I'm after is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to just use a maximum filter and then reset any regions that were "invaded".

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

B = ndimage.maximum_filter(A, 3)
B[A != 0] = A[A != 0]

print B
```

This yields:

```
[[1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0]
 [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

In the dilated areas, the biggest number always "wins".  It's one approach, at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [2D nearest-neighbor interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html) to dilate label regions and fill all zero values.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate as it
from scipy import ndimage as nd


A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
mask = ~(A == 0)
xy = np.where(mask)
interp = it.NearestNDInterpolator(np.transpose(xy), A[xy])
B = interp(*np.indices(A.shape))
print(B)
```

This yields:

```
[[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3]
 [1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3]]
```

Then, with the [binary dilation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html), you can set the number of  pixels you want the label regions to be dilated using iterations. In our case 1 pixel so `iterations=1`

```
C = nd.binary_dilation(mask, structure=np.ones((3,3)), iterations=1).astype(A.dtype)
D = C * B

print(D)
```

This yields:

```
[[1 1 1 2 2 2 0 0]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3]
 [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3] 
 [0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```